# How to stop gnome-remote-desktop from command line?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-22.04, gnome-shell

The 'gnome-remote-desktop' takes up about 0.5G GPU memory, so I want it to be stopped.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiD1q.png)
I hope it is just being temporarily stopped, not uninstalled, in case if sometime I will use it.

I've tried to kill it, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `systemctl`:

```bash
systemctl stop --user gnome-remote-desktop.service
```